# Must I include dependent libraries in boost?

Tags: android, serialization, boost, makefile

I'm entering month 3 of trying to build an Android project that uses boost for serialization.

So, I am compiling Boost 1.49 with Serialization, along with about 8 other libraries such as date_time, filesystem, iostream, etc..
Before now, trying to just build Serialization without those libraries lead to some errors to the tune of `no such file or directory: assert.hpp` in archive.o. So! There are dependencies between libraries when building boost. Got it.

Now, when I go to include the static libraries in my Android project, will I want to include each of those dependent libraries as well, or can I just link to the Serialization library that I'm really interested in?  My guess is that I'll have to link to Serialization and each dependent static library, as well, but I'd like to know for sure. (Not having to include them all would save me a lot of time, trial, and error).

Is there an easy way to see what the dependencies between boost libraries are, so I'll know in the future when building boost what I'll actually need to compile Serialization, or which libraries to include in a project (if more than just the ones I want)? Getting boost to finally compile has been something of a 'spray and pray' approach.

Comment: @Chintan Rathod - please do not add "Thanks" to questions; it is against the FAQ.  Also, please do not randomly use code tags to emphasize words.  [This edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1610985#./1610985?&_suid=136197458292108361549843268694) should not have been approved.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: I just rolled it back, and changed the error formatting to code. (and apparently had a mid-air collision with your edit, sorry)

Comment: @Hasturkun - no worries, it looks better now.  Time to clean up all of the rest of his edits...

Comment: What dependecies exactly? I guess `Boost.Serialization` depends on some core boost libraries, like Functional `SmartPointer`, `Utility` etc. But note that most of boost libraries are header-only, so you don't have to build/link them.